java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Car audio context 0 is invalid
Process: com.android.car, PID: 950
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Car audio context 0 is invalid
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:77)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarAudioContext.preconditionCheckAudioContext(CarAudioContext.java:559)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarAudioZone.getAddressForContext(CarAudioZone.java:241)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarHalAudioUtils.audioAttributeToMetadata(CarHalAudioUtils.java:79)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarHalAudioUtils.audioAttributesToMetadatas(CarHalAudioUtils.java:95)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarDuckingUtils.generateDuckingInfo(CarDuckingUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarDucking.generateNewDuckingInfoLocked(CarDucking.java:125)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarDucking.updateDuckingForZoneIdLocked(CarDucking.java:90)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarDucking.onFocusChange(CarDucking.java:79)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarZonesAudioFocus.notifyFocusListeners(CarZonesAudioFocus.java:270)
    at com.android.car.audio.CarZonesAudioFocus.onAudioFocusRequest(CarZonesAudioFocus.java:214)
    at android.media.audiopolicy.AudioPolicy$EventHandler.handleMessage(AudioPolicy.java:1056)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8194)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

On Android 14, I modified the audioUseDynamicRouting and audioUseCoreRouting properties in/packages/services/Car/service/res/values/config. xml to be true.
Then, when creating a Car instance object through the app, i.e. Car.createCar(), a crash occurred and the error message was as shown above. I would like to ask everyone how to resolve this issue，thanks.
I tried to change the value of the audioUseCoreRouting property to false, but the application did not crash when calling the Car.createCar interface.
However, I did not achieve my goal because I wanted to set the value to true so that the application could still run normally.
